# How to set EntryAssembly for tests in .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, mstest, appdomain, .net-core-3.1

I am currently migrating a project and it's test projects from .Net Framework to .Net Core.

In .Net Framework, we used to be able to do something like this to set the EntryAssembly for tests :

```
AppDomainManager manager = new AppDomainManager();
FieldInfo entryAssemblyfield = manager.GetType().GetField("m_entryAssembly", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
entryAssemblyfield.SetValue(manager, assembly);

AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
FieldInfo domainManagerField = domain.GetType().GetField("_domainManager", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
domainManagerField.SetValue(domain, manager);
```

Taken from here : https://dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2015/january/set-entry-assembly-in-unit-testing-methods/

Since AppDomainManager is not available in .Net Core anymore, how can we accomplish something similar so that `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();` returns what I want instead of the tests project assembly.

Comment: Did you try `Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()`?

Comment: I think that you should take a step back and think about why you're calling this method directly in code that you which to test.  By calling Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() in your code you're coupling your code to this static method.  It would be better if you created an IAssemblyInfo interface (or something like that) and used that in your code.  For actual execution the implementation would call Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(), but for test you could supply whatever value you want.

Comment: @lukaszberwid, In my case `Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()` will not work because I go through a different Assembly between the test assembly and where I call `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()`. If you need more info on my structure let me know I can update my question.

Comment: @ajz, Interesting suggestion, I will try this out and let you know if it works.

Comment: i agree to using an interface so that you can mock the class for test purposes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are two possible solutions I found :

1) Like @ajz suggested, you can create an interface with a GetEntryAssembly method that returns `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` that you could Mock/Setup to return whatever you want for your tests.

2) You can create a class with GetEntryAssembly Func like this :

```
public static class AssemblyHelper
{
    public static Func<Assembly> GetEntryAssembly = () => Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
}
```

In your test method you can override this behavior by reassigning an in-line function to it :

```
AssemblyHelper.GetEntryAssembly = () => assembly;
```

We went with the second solution simply because we used to call `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` inside a static constructor and I don't think there's anyway I can mock an object and set it to a field before going through that.